# What does "are you root?" mean?

Tags: command-line, apt, root

This is what I keep getting:

```
ascendermedia@magic2tower:~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
bash: sudo: command not found
ascendermedia@magic2tower:~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
bash: sudo: command not found
ascendermedia@magic2tower:~$ apt-get install flashplugin-installer
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
ascendermedia@magic2tower:~$ sudo aptitude install flashplugin-nonfree
bash: sudo: command not found
ascendermedia@magic2tower:~$ aptitude install flashplugin-nonfree
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
ascendermedia@magic2tower:~$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28):

`root` is the superuser account on the system — it (basically) has all privileges. Many systems are configured so that you can use the `sudo` command in front of another command to run that command "as root" — that is, as if you are the root user, with the same privileges.

It is usually the case that you need root privileges to install system packages, which is what `apt-get` does. So, it doesn't work, the first time because you don't have `sudo` available; the second time because `sudo` didn't magically appear just because you ran it twice; and the third (and fifth) times because `apt-get` (and `aptitude`) really do require root privs to install packages like this.

As you see from your first error message, sudo is either not installed or not in your path, and probably not configured. You may be able to substitute `su -c` instead, and give the root password (the password for the `root` account) when prompted.

If you don't know that password, you need to a) ask the person who does to perform this task for you, if it is not your system, or b) find some way to recover it.

Comment: This is mostly right, though I would mention that `sudo` doesn't just run commands "as if you were root," it actually runs them as root. If you look at the process, you will see it's running as root, not as your user id. Incidentally, on machines that aren't set up to allow interactive login by root by default, you can just run `sudo bash` to get a root shell. :)

Comment: @reirab I think that `sudo -i` is preferred though, since it respects your current shell.

Comment: @new123456 sudo -i will use the default shell for root. sudo -s will use the value of $SHELL for the executing user.

Comment: @reirab You're quoting from the part where I'm giving an explanation of what "as root" means from a simplified user's point of view.

Answer (score 6):

## What does “are you root?” mean?

In order to install packages systemwide (what `apt-get` does), it needs root privileges, since you will be creating and changing system files (`root` is the usual name for the *nix administrator account).

The «are you root?» message is a gentle reminder that you "need to be root" in order to run `apt-get install`. This is the most often encountered reason for the problem it had (shown above):

> /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

.

## How to become root?

### su

The traditional way of "becoming root" is to run `su` (and provide the password of the root user). [su(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/su.1.html) stands for **s**uper**u**ser or **s**witch **u**ser.

Note it can be used to become any user, so you can run `su john` to get a shell as john. Running `su` with no username is a shorthand for `su root`.

For this to work, the root user account must be enabled and have a password set. Some systems are configured (even by default), with the root account disabled, in order to avoid someone -eg. an attacker- login with the administrator account. In those cases they offer another way to run administrative commands, like sudo.

### sudo

[sudo(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/sudo.8.html) is a program that allows you to execute a command as another user (like above, usually done for root). It is configured in `/etc/sudoers`, and allows a more finer control, such as only allow to run a single program as root, to a specific user (which may be set to require their own password again), and also provides logging facilities (eg. "john executed destroy-system as root").

There are other options for runinng with increased privileges (such as [calife](https://www.keltia.net/programs/calife/)) but they have a much lower usage.

Your above log indicates `sudo` isn't installed on magic2tower.

Answer (score 5):

You need root privileges in order to execute system updates via `apt-get`.

You can switch to a root account using `su root`. It appears that you do not have the `sudo` program installed.

Comment: The OP doesn't just lack `sudo` privileges, he doesn't even have `sudo` installed.

Comment: Updated, ty. +1

Comment: Really, OP should su to root just long enough to install and set up `sudo`.

Comment: @n.st possibly incorrect, it might not be in `PATH`.

Comment: @Kevin I don't recommend having `sudo` available, it leads to people who use it as a "I got an error, try to fix it" instead of thinking about their problems.

Comment: @o11c I'd argue those are the same people who would never encounter that problem without sudo because they're always logged in as root.

Comment: @o11c I use `sudo` several times a day. It would be a significant inconvenience if I had to log in to the root account every time I needed to install a program or launch a web server.

Comment: @o11c While possible, that doesn't seem likely, especially since `sudo` and `apt-get` are both installed to `/usr/bin` by default (at least on Debian).

Answer (score 0):

They have already explain what root is, when you have a "command not found" probably is because you don't have installed the program that your trying to run, or you dont have the path in your env variables.

Try runing the comand like this:

```
/usr/bin/sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

In some linux distros you can't change to root so every command mas be run with sudo. =)

Comment: yeh sure if you have a message like `bash: sudo: command not found` the best idea is to install it with `sudo apt-get install sudo`, and if it gives you the same error you will learn what recursion is

Comment: You cannot install sudo using `sudo`.