# Installing a package without sudoer

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I ran the command `apt-get install squid` and got the following message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

It looks like I need to be a root to install a package. Is there a way to do it without `sudo`?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to UL StackExchange. Thank you for your question. Please also check related questions, for instance [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657258/e-could-not-open-lock-file-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-13-permission-d) which may help you with your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "are you root?" mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213638/what-does-are-you-root-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need admin (root) access to install packages.

If you want a copy of squid to play with then you could always try and build it from the source. But it may have dependencies that will also need installing before you can build it, so would be in the same position of needing root access to install them.

Comment: I wanted to run a proxy server on the Linux box. Is it possible to do that in this case as I don't have root access. Or the only possibility is to download the source and build it?

Comment: It is possible to build and run it, but there may be other problems that will stop it being useful if you don't have root access. E.g. not being able to open a port in the firewall to allow clients to connect to it. I suggest you talk to the machines admin and ask them to install squid for you.

Comment: Thanks. Also, is there any way to check if some proxy servers are already installed?